# Updating table recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update a table with values from the same table but it's failing because it seems the order of the update is important.

The idea is to set the `P0` and `P1` values with the parents ID instead of null for rows 2 and 3.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
    (ID varchar(20),
    ParentId varchar(20),
    P0 varchar(20),
    P1 varchar(20),
    P2 varchar(20),
)

INSERT INTO #Test values ('100000','HEAD','100000', null, null);
INSERT INTO #Test values ('100100','100000',null, '100100', null);
INSERT INTO #Test values ('100200','100100',null, null, '100200');  

UPDATE U SET U.P1 = S.P1 FROM #Test U INNER JOIN #Test S ON S.ID = U.ParentID WHERE U.P2 IS NOT NULL
UPDATE U SET U.P0 = S.P0 FROM #Test U INNER JOIN #Test S ON S.ID = U.ParentId WHERE U.P1 IS NOT NULL 
    
SELECT * FROM #Test
DROP table #Test
```

If I run the above the `P0` value in row 3 is not updated unless I run the last statement again. I'm guessing it's because when it tries to update `100200`, `100100` doesn't have a value yet, it then does `100100` and updates it from `100000`. Any way around this? The actual table and data are `7` levels deep.

Answer (score -1):

```
WHILE (SELECT count(*) FROM #Test WHERE (P0 IS NULL OR P1 IS NULL) AND ParentId<>'HEAD')  > 0
BEGIN  
 UPDATE U SET U.P0 = S.P0 FROM #Test U INNER JOIN #Test S ON S.ID = U.ParentId WHERE U.P1 IS NOT NULL; 
 UPDATE U SET U.P1 = S.P1 FROM #Test U INNER JOIN #Test S ON S.ID = U.ParentID WHERE U.P2 IS NOT NULL;
END;
```

EDITED: As an answer to comments I propose to improve my solution as follows:

```
WHILE (SELECT count(*) FROM Test202011 WHERE (P0 IS NULL OR P1 IS NULL) AND ParentId<>'HEAD')  > 0
    BEGIN  
        UPDATE TOP(1000) U SET U.P0 = S.P0 FROM Test202011 U INNER JOIN Test202011 S ON S.ID = U.ParentId WHERE U.P1 IS NOT NULL; 
        UPDATE TOP(1000) U SET U.P1 = S.P1 FROM Test202011 U INNER JOIN Test202011 S ON S.ID = U.ParentID WHERE U.P2 IS NOT NULL;
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
    END;
```

I am not sure that delay operator is necessary, professional comments/advise are welcome!

Comment: A cursor or a loop are almost *never* the answer to a SQL problem. This loop may work for a few rows but will end up blocking the entire table in production

Comment: I agree with Panagiotis, while it may work in this instance, I would never put this into a production environment (not to mention the 7 level depth),